# How to add parameters in jenkins job dsl

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to create a pipeline template using job dsl. My template looks somewhat like this.

```
//template defnition
def pipelineTemplate(String type) {
 pipelineJob("RajiTesting/${service}/${pipeline_name}-${type}-pipeline") {
    definition {
        cps {
            sandbox(true)
            properties {
        parameters {
          // for type = 'ci'
          stringParam('ticket_id', '')
          stringParam('data_id', '')
          choiceParam('type',['CI/CD Track','NON-CI']) 
          // for type = 'non-ci'
          choiceParam('type',['BUGFIX','RELEASE']) 
        }
    }
script (
//code
)
}
}
}
}
```

I am not able to add conditions in the parameters section as they don't support script.
I am initializing parameters here because this loads the parameters without the need of triggering a build to load parameters in pipeline. Help me solve this.

Comment: For the string parameter you have to put just `string` not `stringParam`

Comment: In job dsl, we can use stringParam.